# PnP Apply template (Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate) issue on 3 level deep parented content types

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, pnp-provision

When applying a site template with a custom content type with a custom parent of an SP internal content type (Document) parent, the following error occurs:
"The parent content type specified by content type identifier.."

The SP internal content type is publish.

Any thoughts?
And please ignore the Publishing site collection feature approach, this is not related.

Comment: Could you share your content type schema?  specially ID of your custom content type?

Comment: any content type that is based on ootb-based content type requires for parent content type to be added once to a site list in order to have it exported to the pnp template. This make no sense, because those content types are published across the tenant.

Comment: To prevent the apply template error, you can temporarily include the parent element in the site template and then remove it. This will create the necessary footprint.